# FPDF different page size (documentation is out of date?)

Tags: python, pdf

So the below piece of code adds images to a PDF

```
def __create(self):
    if len(self.__DLImages) == 0:
        raise Exception("No images to add to PDF")
    else:
        maxWidth  = max([Image.open(imgPath).size[0] for imgPath in self.__DLImages])
        maxHeight = max([Image.open(imgPath).size[1] for imgPath in self.__DLImages])
        PDF = FPDF(unit = "pt", format = (maxWidth, maxHeight))

        for imgPath in self.__DLImages:
            PDF.add_page()
            PDF.image(imgPath, x = self.__margin, y = self.__margin)

        PDF.output(self.__outputFile)
```

But i have to set the height and width to the max dimensions so the images fit on which causes the smaller images to have huge space around.

The documentation says i can set the width and height on the image [Link](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html) but when i do nothing changes as i have set the dimensions of the page already (which i have to so they fit) otherwise it defaults to A4

It also says i can change the dimensions of the page [Link](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/add_page/index.html) but after looking at the source code the `add_page()` method doesn't take any other parameter apart from `orientation` Which is not what this answer suggests [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161733/fpdf-how-can-i-have-different-pages-with-different-sizes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
def __create(self):
    c = canvas.Canvas(self.__outputFile)
    for imgPath in self.__DLImages:
        with PIL.Image.open(imgPath) as loadedImage:
            w, h = loadedImage.size
        c.setPageSize((w, h))
        c.drawImage(imgPath, x = 0, y = 0)
        c.showPage()
    c.save()
```

I found a new module and completed this solution