# How to use PyPDF2 to insert *.png image file into a .pdf file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

here is my code:

```
input_file = "example.pdf"
output_file = "example-drafted.pdf"
watermark_file = "draft.pdf"

with open(input_file, "rb") as filehandle_input:
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(filehandle_input)

    with open(watermark_file, "rb") as filehandle_watermark:
         watermark = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(filehandle_watermark)
         first_page = pdf.getPage(0)
         first_page_watermark = watermark.getPage(0)
         first_page.mergePage(first_page_watermark)
         pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()       
         pdf_writer.addPage(first_page)

         with open(output_file, "wb") as filehandle_output:
              pdf_writer.write(filehandle_output)
```

in my above code :
watermark_file = "draft.pdf".

i want this watermark_file to be used as "draft.png"

Comment: Check out ```reportlab```. Here is an snippet of code to insert a PNG into a PDF. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44750289/4180176

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if I understood your problem well but you seem to be in trouble for adding a PNG picture in a PDF?

You may consider using `PDFKit` instead of `PyPDF2`, which provides a way easier method for dealing with PDFs from a personal perspective.

For instance, you could create a HTML page containing your `draft.png` and then add it to your PDF file.

I found a good example for this method on this blog if you are interested :

http://yoroshikune.com/creating-pdf-files-python/

Comment: Could you insert the relevant parts of the link you provided as quoted text in your own post? Links go dead...